# BehaviorSubject returns the initial value although it gets changed in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular8, behaviorsubject

When I log in, I am doing a post call to my server and am getting some data. I want to save that data to my BehaviorSubject. Although it gets updated, when I subscribed to it in order to get it to another component, I am getting its initial value.

**login.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  private data = new BehaviorSubject('default');
  public cData = this.data.asObservable();

constructor(private router: Router, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public login(userName: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const options: any = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
    };
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`/login`, { username: userName, password }, options)
      .pipe(
        tap((result: any) => {
          this.changeData(result.data);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/main-page');
          return;
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          return of(error);
        })
      );
  }

public changeData(data: string): void {
    this.data.next(data);
}
```

**login.component.ts**:

```
  public onSubmit(loginForm: NgForm): void {
    this.loginService.login(loginForm.value.username, loginForm.value.password).subscribe((result) => {
      this.loginService.cDataa.subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); //I AM GETTING THE DATA
      });
    });
  }
```

**main-page.component.ts**:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginService.cDataa.subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data); //I AM NOT GETTING THE DATA BUT I GET default
    });
  }
```

In tha **main-page.module.ts**, I inserted the LoginService in the providers.

Comment: You should remove LoginService from the providers. It will work because you specified 'providedIn: root' in the @Injectable() decorator. My feeling is that you have two different instances of the LoginService. Please tell if that solves the issue.

Comment: @CristianSarghe yes, that was the problem indeed. I deleted the LoginService in every provider of any component. Thanks!!